# grep with PCRE to return after multiple whitespace occurrences

Tags: grep

I am trying to have grep return both interfaces `1/1.2` AND `1/1.6` but I can't find a way to return both, only the first.

```
net trunk dmz_trunk { bandwidth 20000 cfg-mbr-count 2 id 1 interfaces { 1/1.2 1/1.6 } lacp enabled mac-address f4:15:63:c9:7b:e1 media 10000 working-mbr-count 2 }
```

I've tried:

```
grep  -oP '(interfaces {)\s+\K\S+\S+')
```

I am getting the first `1/1.2` but not the second `1/1.6`

Any ideas with grep or do I need to use awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to further use `grep` with the PCRE engine you may leverage the [`\G` construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) to build a custom left-hand boundary and grab all values you need after `interface {` and before the next `}` using

```
grep  -oP '(?:\G(?!^)|interfaces\s*{)\s*\K[^{}\s]+'
```

See the [`grep` online demo](https://ideone.com/jhjqeN) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hUTU9s/1).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|interfaces\s*{)` - either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) `interfaces`, 0+ whitespaces, `{` (`interfaces\s*{`)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)
- `[^{}\s]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace, `{` and `}`

Comment: That's excellent and it will also capture if I have 3 or more interfaces within the {}. Awesome. Thanks.